# Propper container logs monitoring in Ansible/Rundeck

Tags: docker, logging, ansible, continuous-integration, rundeck

I am using Ansible and Rundeck to deploy docker containers, one of which starts generating logs which I would like to make visible in Rundeck. I know i can do it with an Ansible playbook that does
`docker container logs {{container_name}} --until=5s`
pauses for 5 sec and does this over and over but is there a proper plugin/module in either Ansible or Rundeck to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Ansible playbooks / inline-playbooks on Rundeck without changes, take a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNjcPJeLVxo, the plugin is built with Rundeck out of the box, and here full documentation about how to use: https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but i'm already using this plugin,the issue is that logs are transfered only at the end of every ansible task